# tcolorbox is not breaking between pages

Tags: luatex, page-breaking, tcolorbox

I am working on a resume and am facing an issue with breaking up sections between pages. I was first using minipage and then learned that minipage does not break, but I've read tcolorblock supports this. So I made tried using tcolorblock, but the behavior of it doesn't appear any different.

I tried to create a MWE, but since I'm so new to LaTeX (and specifically, luatex) I was unable to do so. The best I can do for now is provide an example via Overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/read/tnttrzgbyhvt

If you take a look at that example you will see the problem I'm facing. Line `398` in the `cls` file shows what I've tried to do with tcolorblock. For convenience, this is here:

```
\newcommand\workexperience[8]{
    \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced jigsaw,breakable,pad at break*=1mm,break at=9cm,
      opacityback=0,colframe=white!75!black,title=\textbf{#1 \hfill \textsc{#2} --- \textsc{#3}},
      watermark color=white,watermark]
      %\textbf{#1 \hfill \textsc{#2} --- \textsc{#3}}\\*
      \emph{#4, \textsc{#5}, #6}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\smallskip\\*
        #7\smallskip
      \center\footnotesize{\faTags Skills: \foreach \n in {#8}{\cvtag{\n}}}
    \end{tcolorbox}\smallskip\\
}
```

And the text is coming from the `section_experiences.tex` file. Anyway, you can see that `tcolorbox 2` does not start on the first page because there isn't enough room for the entire box. And `tcolorbox 4` fills up the entire page, and you will see that it is not breaking into the next page (a bunch of text gets cut off). I've tried using tags like `break at=10cm` but that doesn't appear to make any difference. I just want the sections to break and continue onto the next page. Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: Please note that always provide the `MW\E` from `\documentclass{...}` to `\end{document}`

Answer (score 1):

I believe I found the answer -- it looks like it wouldn't work before because it was nested inside an unbreakable element. In this case, it was nested inside of:

```
\newenvironment{experiences}{%
  \begin{longtable}{c}
}{%
  \end{longtable}
}
```

Perhaps longtable is unbreakable. When I changed the `section_experiences.tex` from:

```
\begin{experiences}
    \workexperience
    {tcolorbox 1} {Begin Date}{End Date}
    {Company}{City}{State}
    {
        \begin{itemize}
            \item \lipsum[1]
            \item \lipsum[1]
```

To:

```
\begin{workexperience}
    {tcolorbox 1} {Begin Date}{End Date}
    {Company}{City}{State}
    {
        \begin{itemize}
            \item \lipsum[1]
            \item \lipsum[1]
```

It appears to be working as expected! :)